# Javascript - React Data from Async fetching is undefined using 'useEffect()' and 'useState'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react. I'm trying to fetch some data from API. I want to fetch a user. However, the user is undefined later when I want to process the user data. I'm confused about how the async function works.

I want to fetch a user, then pass the user to `UserInfo` component. In the `UserInfo` component, I want to process the data before I display it on the website. I got an error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined".

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

App.js

```
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [user, setUser] = useState({})
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      const userFromServer = await fetchUser()
      if (userFromServer) {
        setUser(userFromServer)
      } else {
        console.log("error")
      }
    }

    const getPosts = async () => {
      const postsFromServer = await fetchPosts()
      setPosts(postsFromServer)
    }

    const getUserList = async () => {
      const userListFromServer = await fetchUserList()
      setUserList(userListFromServer)
    }

    getUser()
    getPosts()
    getUserList()
  }, [])

  // Fetch user 
  const fetchUser = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }

  // Fetch posts
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1')
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }

  // Fetch list of users
  const fetchUserList = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Box className={classes.headerImage}>
        <UserMenu userList = {userList} />
      </Box>
      <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.userContainer}>
        <UserInfo user = {user} />
      </Container>
      <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.blogsContainer}>
        <PostList name = {user.name} posts = {posts} />
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
} 

export default App;
```

UserInfo.js

```
    const classes = useStyles()

    console.log(user.phone)
    const phoneStr = user.phone.split(" ")[0]

    // var companyStr = user.company.bs.replaceAll(" ", "· ")

    // const addressDic = user.address
    // const addressStr = addressDic.street + " " + addressDic.suite + " " + addressDic.city + " " +addressDic.zipcode

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{user.name}</h2>
            <Paper elevation={0} className={classes.paper}>
                <Grid container>
                    <Grid item xs={1}>
                        <img className={classes.icon} src={phoneIcon} />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item className={classes.gridText} xs={11}>
                        {phoneStr}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid xs={1}>
                        <img className={classes.icon} src={categoryIcon} />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item className={classes.gridText} xs={11}>
                        
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={1}>
                        <img className={classes.icon} src={shopIcon} />    
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item className={classes.gridText} xs={11}>
                        
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Paper>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserInfo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because the user info is not always available. While you wait the fetch user data the component tree continues to render. `user.phone` will be undefined and `undefined.split()` causes an error.

You can solve this by first checking for existence of user.phone before calling split.

```js
user.phone && user.phone.split(" ")[0]
```

However this will only solve one line, you'll need to do this for every lookup in the User component which isn't great. It would be better to set the default state for user to null.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
```

And then only render the User component when user is not null

```
      <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.userContainer}>
        { user ? <UserInfo user = {user} /> : 'loading...'} 
      </Container>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Can I ask what is the process behind this code? Does react automatically and constantly check whether the fetched user exists and only render the component when the data become available? So that I don't have to write my own loop to check when it will be available? I want to do a loading page too, but I think I should understand how it works first.

Comment: React will handle it all for you. Whenever the state changes react will rerender and show the component appropriately based on that new state. You can replace the loading string with a custom component of course.

Answer (score 0):

First, grab your call in a `Promise.all`, this way you are sure that all your calls are correctly executed before setting the states, in your `useEffect`:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const getUser = async () => await fetchUser();
   const getPosts = async () => await fetchPosts();
   const getUserList = async () => await fetchUserList();

   (async () => {
     try {
       const [response1, response2, response3] = await Promise.all(getUser(), getPosts(), getUserList());
       userFromServer && setUser(response1);
       setPosts(response2);
       setUserList(response3);
     } catch (err) {
       throw new Error(`Something went wrong: ${err}`);
     }
   })();
 }, []);
```

Then, in your return, wait until user data is set, something like:

```
{user?.phone && <UserInfo user={user} />}
```